# How to/Should I optimize sql server on low memory machine?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a 1GB memory virtual machine on cloud, with Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2014 Express and IIS 8 installed. Should I optimize it's max 'Max Server Memory' option or something else to boost it's performance?

Comment: 1GB Memory :S , if you are serious about your application you would spend some money and get more memory, not expensive at all these days.

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) site is a better choice for this question.

Comment: Express can't take more than 1GB memory anyway (buffer pool). But after the OS and IIS and the SQLServer engine is installed, you will be left with very little to work with. Maybe try an install of  Windows Server 2012 Core instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Your memory is very low and you need more memory for your server.

[Suggested Max Memory Settings By Glenn Berry's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/glennberry/2009/10/29/suggested-max-memory-settings-for-sql-server-2005_2F00_2008/)

These settings are for x64, on a dedicated database server, only running the DB engine, (which is the ideal situation).

```
Physical RAM                        MaxServerMem Setting 
2GB                                           1500 
4GB                                           3200 
6GB                                           4800 
8GB                                           6400 
12GB                                         10000 
16GB                                         13500 
24GB                                         21500 
32GB                                         29000 
48GB                                         44000 
64GB                                         60000
72GB                                         68000
96GB                                         92000
128GB                                       124000
```